# Where's the CefSharp DLL that includes the "IWebBrowser" type?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, reference, cefsharp

I'm porting my app from Microsoft Edge WebView2 to CefSharp because of the extension support, however for some reason, `IWebBrowser` seems to be placed in a DLL that is either hidden or not installed.

I've added the xaml namespace and the `ChromiumWebBrowser` control. What should I do and where is the missing DLL?

Visual Studio suggested I install the CefSharp.Common NuGet package, which I did, but that never added the DLL or the reference to it.

It also said I should add a reference to a DLL, but I don't know where it is.

Comment: Should be IWebBrowser2 : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,5675b8c7e9940807   It is an unsafe native method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Visual Studio suggested I install the CefSharp.Common NuGet package, which I did, but that never added the DLL or the reference to it.

`Visual Studio` was spot on when it suggested `CefSharp.Common`. [IWebBrowser](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/118.6.x/html/T_CefSharp_IWebBrowser.htm) is part of `CefSharp.dll` which comes packaged in `CefSharp.Common`.

You can browser the package online at https://nuget.info/packages/CefSharp.Common/120.2.70 where you can see it's in the `\lib\net462` folder as you'd expect.